# How to make form_rest() not display a field with Symfony2?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I've started to use Symfony2 but I've some problems.
I wanted to render fields by hand but it doesn't work because my field yet rendered by me is displayed with the `form_rest()` function too, so I have two same fields.

Here is my code :

```
<div>
     {{ form_errors(form.contenu) }}
     <textarea id="{{ form.contenu.vars.id }}" name="{{ form.contenu.vars.full_name }}">{{ form.contenu.vars.value }}</textarea>
</div>
```

And, at the form's end, I must put this :

```
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

But it displays the "contenu" field :(

Do you have an idea of what's the problem ?

Comment: Is, by any chance, your form called "form"? At which version of Symfony this solution worked for you?
I'm trying to do the same but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Another option is to explicitly mark the field as rendered:

```
{% do form.contenu.setRendered %}
```

Comment: in PHP it would be <?php $form['contenu']->setRendered(true) ?>

Comment: @TomasDermisek No `\Symfony\Component\Form\FormView::setRendered` has no arguments. And since there is no `setUnrendered` and `$rendered` is a private method, you can't use `{{ form_row(form.contenu) }}` later on in your code.

Comment: @StephanVierkant, the trick is to first do `{% set formDescription = form_row(form.description) %}` then `{{ form_rest(form) }}` and then `{{ formDescription|raw }}`.

Answer (score 65):

Another *in my opinion* less hacky way to do it is this:

```
{{ form_widget(form._token) }} // render the CSRF Token
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }} // do not render anything else
```

It's from the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-rest-view-variables) (v3.0) so it's pretty much *best practise* i guess.

Comment: `{{ form_widget(form._token) }}`

Answer (score 33):

`{{ form_rest(form) }}` goes at the very end, after rendering each field "manually". If you are using it for the CSRF token you can always render it with:

```
{# Token CSRF #}
{{ form_widget(form._token) }}
```

Comment: very useful in combination with 
`{{ form_widget(form._token) }}`
`{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}`

Answer (score 10):

The situation in which you don't want to show some field suggests badly designed form. You could feed some argument(s) into it's `__construct` to make it conditional (say, include/exclude some fields) or you could just create separate `Form` classes (which is, in my opinion, a bit overkill).

I had common case few months ago when form differed when user inserted/updated records. It was something like this:

```
...
public function __construct($isUpdateForm){
    $this->isUpdateForm= $isUpdateForm;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options){
    ....
    $builder->add('some_filed', 'text', ..... );

    if ( $this->isUpdateForm ){
        $builder->add(.....);
    }
    ....
}
....
```

If for some reasons you're not able to refactor form class you could still display unwanted fields but wrap them into `<div>` which has CSS `display:none` attribute. That way "they are still there" (and by all means are processed normally) but are not visible to user.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank, but that wasn't what I want (I've found a solution, see my EDIT). I wanted to say to Symfony I've already display the field ;)

Comment: Even better would be different forms for adding or updating an entity. My experience is that you'll add `$isUpdateForm` to your constructor, later on you'll add `$isAdmin` and `$isOwner`, etc. etc.

Comment: @StephanVierkant while I had no such case so far, that is certainly a possibility. But then, with individual forms, dev should pay attention to minimize duplication (or have none at all). Nothing is worse than fixing a bug in one place, just to uncover that there is a same snippet that you really haven’t been aware of at all... :-)