# form_end prints unwanted labels

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I'm creating a form in `Symfony2`, one of my fields is a `collection` field  & I'm using it in form like this:

```
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}

            ...

            <div>
                {{ form_label(form.tels) }} 
                <a href="#" id="add-another-tel">+</a>
                <ul id="tels-fields-list" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.tels.vars.prototype)|e }}">
                {% for telsField in form.tels %}
                    <li>
                        {{ form_errors(telsField) }}
                        {{ form_widget(telsField) }}
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
                </ul>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var telCount = '{{ form.tels|length }}';
                    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                        jQuery('#add-another-tel').click(function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();                 
                            var telsList = jQuery('#tels-fields-list');
                            var newWidget = telsList.attr('data-prototype');
                            newWidget = newWidget.replace(/__name__/g, telCount);
                            telCount++;
                            var newLi = jQuery('<li></li>').html(newWidget);
                            newLi.appendTo(telsList);
                        });
                    })
                </script>
            </div>

            ...

        {{ form_rest(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

While I'm calling `{{ form_label(form.tels) }}` but at the end of the form & when `{{ form_end(form) }}` is called the label of this field is printed again.
So I have two labels for this field (one at the correct position & another at the end of the form).
This occurs as many as collection fields I have.

What is the problem?

Comment: Try to add `{% do telsField.setRendered %}` inside of the loop. Or at the place you insert the element of the form, replacing `telsField` with what you have.

Comment: @Cheery: No effect! still prints additional labels

Comment: Did you try `{% do form.tels.setRendered %}`? But I think it will disable the output of not only the label. This tells that field was printed, used it a couple of times, but for the whole field, not only labels.

Comment: @Cheery: using `{% do form.tels.setRendered %}` at the end fixed it; Thanks

Comment: Yes, I remember that I found it here, for the first time )) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570002/how-to-make-form-rest-not-display-a-field-with-symfony2

Comment: As it is already solved maybe @Cheery you can post your answer? Or it can be closed as duplicate of above question?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov I think it is a duplicate.