# How to load only a subset of a OneToMany association in a form?

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities: `A` and `B`. `A` is associated to `B` through a `OneToMany` association:

```php
class A
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="..\AcmeBundle\Entity\B", mappedBy="A", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     */
    private $things;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->things = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
    // addThing(), removeThing() and getThings() are properly defined
```

I have a Form class for the `A` entity:

```php
class AThingsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('things', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new BType()
            ))
            ->add('send', 'submit')
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => '..\AcmeBundle\Entity\A'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'a_things';
    }
}
```

The `BType` class contains fields to define the forms of B, there is nothing particular in it.

And I use this form from my controller:

```php
$a = $em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:A')->getAWithSubsetOnly($A_id);

$form = $this->createForm(new AThingsType (), $a /* instance of A*/);
```

Then the form is rendered in the Twig template.

It will add one `BType` for each element in `A->things` but **I want to display only a subset of the `A->strings` values**, because the current user doesn't have the rights to modify all the `A->things`, he can only update some of these `B` entities. I don't know how to do this, because the whole collection of `A->things` is loaded automatically (even if a do a `->innerJoin()` to fetch only a subset of the things) so the form display all the `BType` whereas I only want to display some of them (based on a SQL query).

Now the fields are hidden by calling [`{% do form.contenu.setRendered %}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13490806/2257664) in Twig but I hope there may be a better solution.

Comment: try using the [entity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) form type instead of collection so you can provide the sql query (or repository method) to execute. If is based on user data take a look at [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-user-data)

Comment: @Matteo thanks for your comment, but according to the documentation the entity form type can only display <select>, radio buttons or checkboxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely you're not explicitly selecting the entities you want in your DQL/QueryBuilder call in your getAWithSubsetOnly repository method.

For example, this will get a user and if I wanted to display all its logs as a collection in my form, will lazy load all logs regardless of my criteria:

```
$userData = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder()->select('u') // constraint ignored
    ->from('SomeUserBundle:User', 'u')
    ->join('u.logs', 'l')
    ->where('l.id < 20880')
    ->andWhere('u.id = 7')
    ->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
```

If you explicity tell doctrine to fetch the sub entity at join like below, it won't lazy load the collection & you will get your filtered collection subset:

```
$userData = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder()->select('u, l') // constraint taken into account as
                                           // logs not lazy loaded
    ->from('SomeUserBundle:User', 'u')
    ->join('u.logs', 'l')
    ->where('l.id < 20880')
    ->andWhere('u.id = 7')
    ->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
```

You'll also save yourself a lot of lazy loading SQL queries with this approach.

Comment: The resulting SQL query is different but the OneToMany entities are still loaded, I see them with `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($a);`.

Comment: The `select('u, l')` was the solution and it returned correctly a subset of the `OneToMany`. But there were some functions in the controller which loaded the `OneToMany` before and `Doctrine2` kept them in memory. Once I removed these functions the form only display the subset. Thanks a lot!