# Symfony 2 OneToMany relations - wrong results in association

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, relational-database

I have two tables in DB with OneToMany relations. Using 'createQueryBuilder()' method in 'EntityRepository' i try to select some objects with conditions. There is my method:

```
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $query->select("parent")
        ->from('TestAppBundle:Parent', 'parent')
        ->leftJoin("parent.children", 'child', 'WITH', 'child.IdP = parent.id')
        ->where('child.date < :date')
        ->andWhere('child.status = :null')
        ->setParameter('date', new DateTime())
        ->setParameter('null', 0);
```

And it works almost good. I get Parent Objects with Children Objects in ArrayCollections. Methods select the Parent Objects with conditions but the problem is I get also Children Objects which don't keep the conditions. 
I want to get only Parent Objects which keep conditions and Children Objects which also keep conditions. At this time a have to filter results after query and remove Children Object manualy.
I hope you will understand the problem :)

Comment: What is the condition that the selected children don't meet ?

Comment: Children have i.e. field name "status". This field can be true or false. I want to select only this Parent which Children have status false. It works fine, from i.e. 8000 rows i get 100 Parent Objects but when i want to see Children i get Child with status true and Child with status false. I have to remove Child object which has status true after query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, if you don't select the entities at query time you'll lazy load all children for the parent when you call getChildren(). Select both children and parents like this to avoid lazy loading:

```
$query->select("parent, child")
```

For more information please see [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290767/how-to-load-only-a-subset-of-a-onetomany-association-in-a-form/27303561#27303561).

Comment: Thanks it works! I tried this way before but i thought i got collection with mixed values Parents and Children (two types of objects in one level array). It wasn't true.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$query->select("parent")
    ->from('TestAppBundle:Parent', 'parent')
    ->leftJoin("parent.children", 'child', 'WITH', 'child.status = 0');
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't change anything. I still have to many child objects.

Comment: To bad, could you provide some database info or doctrine mapping file (if you use doctrine).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your needs you should not use `leftJoin` - with this field you will get parents that don't have children. Use `innerJoin` instead.

Assuming that child.IdP refers to the parent.id in your model definition you don't have to use WITH clause in this way. So the queryBuilder would be:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$query->select("parent")
    ->from('TestAppBundle:Parent', 'parent')
    ->innerJoin("parent.children", 'child')
    ->where('child.date < :date and child.status = :null')
    ->setParameter('date', new DateTime())
    ->setParameter('null', 0);
```

Regards.